# Regex Bracket Expressions exclude string

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying find a subtstring of a string using regex. My string is:

```
<p><a class="twitter-share-button" RANDOM STUFF HERE </script>
```

I know there is no script tag in the random stuff so i made a regex that looks like this:

```
<p><a class="twitter-share-button"[^</script>]*
```

But the `[^</script>]` excludes all characters: `<`, `/`, `s`, `c`, `r`, `i`, `p`, `t`, `>`
How can i tell the regex to continue searching until it finds an occurrence of the closing script tag ?

Thanks

Comment: Please tag which programming language you're using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends on the engine, but you can do an ungreedy match:

```
<p><a class="twitter-share-button"(.*?)</script>
```

The `?` makes the `*` ungreedy, so it will match everything up until the first `</script>`.

Comment: @senly show me your `preg_match` code.  Otherwise I can't help you

Comment: `$html=preg_replace('/s <p><a class="twitter-share-button"(.*?)</script>', '', $html);`

Comment: @senly what is with that `s ` at the start of the expression?

Comment: Mistake: `$html = preg_replace("<p><a class=\"twitter-share-button\"(.*?)</script></p>", "", $html);`

Comment: @senly there are a couple of problems.  You have no delimiter and you're ending the pattern with `</p>` (which may still work).

Comment: the </p> is actually in the code, forgot to mention it in the question. What do you call a delimiter ?

Comment: The $html becomes NULL after this line

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23996/discussion-between-explosion-pills-and-senly)